# Possible to stir a drink while maintaining a convex shape?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow

The Wikipedia page for the Brouwer fixed point theorem [has a cute example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem#Illustrations):

> "no matter how much you stir a cocktail in a glass ... when the liquid has come to rest, some point in the liquid will end up in exactly the same place in the glass as before you took any action, assuming that the final position of each point is a continuous function of its original position, that the liquid after stirring is contained within the space originally taken up by it, and that the glass (and stirred surface shape) maintain[s] a convex volume."

(The kicker is that the same should not be said for a shaken cocktail.)

Question: is it possible to stir a cocktail while maintaining a convex shape? My impression from a classic calculus problem is that the sides of the surface would rise up above the center, breaking the convexity condition.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest putting a lid on the cocktail that leaves not free surface.^^
If you have a free surface, you must make sure that it does not move in vertical direction at any point (that's what I want the lid for) because if it did, there would be a minimum of its height profile, where indeed the convexity of the fluid body is broken.

In principle you could try to create a stirring motion that causes purerly horizontal fluid motion... Not sure if that's possible.